# Finding the local maximum of a function with unknown constants

Tags: calculus, statistics, derivatives, optimization

I have a function $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x\cdot977\cdot a\right)}{\left(b\cdot1000+x\cdot997\right)}-\frac{\left(c\cdot x\cdot1000\right)}{997\cdot\left(d-x\right)}$ for which I would like to find the local maximum in the domain $0<x<d$ where $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are all unknown positive constants.

I'm having trouble coming up with an answer, is it possible to mathematically determine the local maximum in that range in terms of $a, b, c,$ and $d$?

Comment: Not in general, imagine $a=c=0$, the maximum is zero. If $a, b, c, d$ are positive numbers, it may be possible.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the clarification that they are all positive numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting $f\left(x\right)=\frac{977x\cdot a}{1000b+997x}+\frac{1000cx}{997(x-d)}=a-\frac{1000ab}{1000b+997x}+\frac{1000c}{997}-\frac{1000cd}{997(x-d)}$

Taking a derivative, $f'(x)=\frac{997000ab}{(1000b+997x)^2}+\frac{1000cd}{997(x-d)^2}$. To find extremum we need to solve $f'(x)=0$ which brings us to this quadratic equation: $997^2\cdot1000ab\cdot(x-d)^2+1000cd\cdot(1000b+997x)^2=0$ or $994009(ab+cd)x^2+1994bd(1000c-997a)x+994009abd^2+1000000cdb^2=0$

Next just the quadratic formula to solve the equation and find $x$

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!